# Creating instance variables only once

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver, instance

Not sure if its called instance variables but you will understand. I want to set variables like this only once. But it´s in receiver. This way they are set every time receiver get message. What is the correct solution for this?

```
android.os.Vibrator v; //declare

public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {
    v = (android.os.Vibrator) mainContext.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE); //getting instance every time
```

Comment: If you want to lazy-initiialize `v`, simply check if `v == null` and only if this is the case, assign the value.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I did not understand the question, but you can declare this variable in the constructor, or as a class variable. Or is there some barrier to not doing so?

```
android.os.Vibrator v; //declare
    
var v = (android.os.Vibrator) mainContext.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);

public void onLocationChanged(@NonNull Location location) {
        //code
}
```

Comment: Wow you really can? I never tried that because i thought its like initializing textview in main activity. You cant put textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView); like that. Makes sence now, thanky

Comment: View are called in onCreate because it is necessary that the UI was already rendered.
More info [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle)